# How to return Multiple Tuples Using Custom Loader Function in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have written a custom loader function by implementing the LoadFunc class.

Now I wanted to return multiple lines as input in the getNext() method.

I have used a DataBag like

```
databag.add(tuple1);
databag.add(tuple2);
```

then

```
tuple3.set(0,databag);
```

and return tuple3 in the getNext() method.

But I got an error

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1071: Cannot convert a bag to a String
```

Can you please guide how to proceed, and if the approach is incorrect, then how to approach this problem.

Thanks, cheers :))

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bag with multiple tuples in it. Then this would be a way to generate it. Generate(set) the tuple first then add those tuples to the databag.

```
BagFactory bf=BagFactory.getInstance();
DataBag output=bf.newDefaultBag();
...
TupleFactory tp=TupleFactory.getInstance();
Tuple t1=tp.newTuple(2);
....
t1.set(0,key_out);
t1.set(1,value_out);
output.add(t1);
return output;
```